# How do I defeat Maria Hill in the Mini-Kart tasks?

Tags: lego-marvel-super-heroes

To unlock Maria Hill, you have to complete her three mini-missions:

Unfortunately, despite watching videos of people successfully defeating her, I'm still stuck on the first race - my cart is actively slower than hers for the entire track.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What platform are you playing on?  I had no trouble with this beyond the awful steering controls.  All I could really think is that you're using a controller with analog face buttons and not pressing the accelerator hard enough?!

Comment: @Shinrai Xbox 360, standard controller.  And yes, the terrible steering makes it worse, but I think she gets a boost at the start that I don't or something as well...

Comment: Do you have trouble driving normally?  I think she does get a little head start (you can see it in the video there) but like most casual racing games if you're taking the corners on the inside you should have no trouble overtaking her.

Comment: I realize this problem has likely come and gone for you, but if there's someone in particular that is still frustrating you, check out my edit :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this just tonight (Xbox 360 version, for what that's worth).

Maria does get a super speed boost at the beginning of the race, but if you floor it and manage to keep from hitting the sides of the track, you will eventually catch up with her.  I don't know if she corners poorly or if her top speed is less than yours, but she doesn't maintain her early lead throughout.

The steering and the camera are the major problems here.  You will generally want to make frequent/rapid small adjustments rather than really throwing the stick to one side or the other.  If you do that, you'll tend to make an overly tight turn suddenly and hit the side of the track.  It takes a few practice runs to get the hang of the curves - the camera tends to fail to keep up with these, so you won't have a clear idea as to where you're going until a few seconds after you turn.

If you can stay on track, you can catch up - I tended to pass her or bump into her between the last checkpoint and the finish line, generally speaking.

---

An Alternate (Cheesy) Method

I discovered after some races with Ghost Rider that sometimes he got off-track and took forever to finish the race.  Some further investigation shows that the AI actually drives the course "legally" - their time changes depending on what kind of traffic and so forth they encounter.

So, what good is this information?  **Just park something in front of NPCs you intend to race.**  They can't quite figure out how to get around it, and will give you a commanding lead while they work it out.

In this specific instance, Maria Hill is on an elevated track.  If you jump down to the vehicle call-in point and summon a helicopter, you can land it on the track in front of her with a bit of effort.  As much as possible, try to keep your side of the track clear.  Then, when you start the race, she'll run into it and give you an advantage.

This is obviously much, much easier on the ground, but it is doable on her track.  I used this trick on the second race with her to great effect.

I'm out of these races now, but I do wonder what would happen if you parked a big character (ie, the Hulk) as your co-op partner in front of her....

Comment: Good ideas. I got through it by ramming into her at the very beginning, negating her initial speed boost and giving me the edge through the rest of the race. In other races, I had my best results when I had a friend actively chase and ram into my opponent to push them off the course.

Answer (score 1):

Do the race with iron man, Halfway through the race, jump out and fly off a little way then come back, Maria's out of her car. You can stroll to your car jump in and do the race on your own

Answer (score 0):

I put a helicopter in front of her before start.  That stopped her from going anywhere.

Comment: This feels like more a comment than an answer